# Pass state value from one component to another

Tags: reactjs

I have an array in the parent component, and I want to pass this state value to another componenet which will the props for another component.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
        import Bookings from "./components/Bookings";
        import Meals from "./components/Meals";
        import Error from "./components/Error";

        class App extends Component {
        state = {
            values: [{ name: "John Doe", date: "2017-09-15" }]
        };

        handleGuestInfo = () => {
            console.log("Here");
            //console.log(this.state.name, "here");
        };
        render() {
            return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <center>
                <h2>Hacker Hostel</h2>
                </center>
                <div className="container">
                <Bookings onGuestChange={this.handleGuestInfo} />
                <Error />
                <Meals name={this.state.values} date={this.state.values} />
                </div>
            </div>
            );
        }
        }

        export default App;


                import React, { Component } from "react";

    class Meals extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <ol id="list">
            <div>
                <li className="morning">
                Breakfast for {this.props.name} on {this.props.date}
                </li>
                <li className="afternoon">Lunch for insert_hacker_name</li>
                <li className="night">Dinner for insert_hacker_name</li>
            </div>
            </ol>
        </div>
        );
    }
    }
    export default Meals;
```

Any help will be appreciated, I want to get name and date to the meals.js file from app.js, I am able to pass value for function.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You are passing the state in your app. It is an array of objects. So you can't render it directly. You need to map over it.

Comment: Why is `values` an array when it only contains a single object? Can it contain more than one? If not then just make it an object and map the fields `<Meals {...this.state.values} />`

Comment: I realized something, you are not passing the state correctly. You are passing the same value (`values`) as two separate props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map over `values` state and render the `Meal` component according to that.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    values: [{ name: "John Doe", date: "2017-09-15" }]
  };

  handleGuestInfo = () => {
    console.log("Here");
    //console.log(this.state.name, "here");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <center>
          <h2>Hacker Hostel</h2>
        </center>
        <div className="container">
        {this.state.values.map(value =>(
          <Meals key={value.name} name={value.name} date={value.date} />
        ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Meals extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <ol id="list">
          <div>
            {this.props.valuy}
            <li className="morning">
              Breakfast for {this.props.name} on {this.props.date}
            </li>
            <li className="afternoon">Lunch for insert_hacker_name</li>
            <li className="night">Dinner for insert_hacker_name</li>
          </div>
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Newbie to react, It did not strike to use map, thank you so much.